# Convert Fullcalendar start/end date for mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Hy i was wondering how can i convert FullCalendar start and end date so i can insert it in database, this is the output given by fullcalendar js:

> end   Thu Aug 16 2012 00:00:00 GMT 0300
>
> start Wed Aug 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT 0300

it can be done either by javascript or php, and this is what i am sending thouth json:

> title=test&start=Wed Aug 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300&end=Thu Aug 16
>   2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300&uid=7

```
> $.ajax({
>       cache: false,
>       type: 'POST',
>       url: siteURL + 'ajax/add_holiday',
>       data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start +'&end=' + end + '&uid=' + '<?php echo $_SESSION['user']->uid; ?>',
>       success: function(data) {
>                   
>       }
>   });
```

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far, and also what format date you even want to get it into. Type out the ajax request etc!

Comment: posted ajax request also the form i need is YYYY MM DD, mysql normal format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FullCalendar's built-in function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/)

```
start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I tried this, but it wouldn't parse the year. Why could that be?
`var st = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "YYYY-MM-dd");`
start does indeed contain the year, but the variable st is assigned the value 'YYYY-08-20' for example.

Comment: Note that the format changed as of version 1.3 - old (before version 1.3): "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" - new (v1.3 and newer): "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"